# Convergence of integral involving the remainder of a Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, lebesgue-integral

Consider the convolution

\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}K(\xi)h\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X-\epsilon\xi\right)d\xi
\end{align}
where $ \psi $ is some sufficiently smooth function, $ h $ is periodic in the first variable and $ K $ decays sufficiently to ensure that $ K(x)h\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X-\epsilon\xi\right) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for all $ X $ and $ \epsilon $. Also assume that $ K(\xi),\xi K(\xi) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) $, and $ h $ has continuous derivatives up to order 2 or 3 in both variables. A Taylor expansion of $ h $ in the second variable yields

\begin{align}
h\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X-\epsilon\xi\right) = h\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X\right) - \epsilon\xi h_2\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X\right) + \epsilon\xi R\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X-\epsilon\xi\right),
\end{align}
where $ h_2 $ denotes a derivative w.r.t the second variable, and the last term is the Peano form of the remainder due to Taylor's theorem. We also know that $ R \in \mathrm{o}(1) $ as $ \epsilon\xi \rightarrow 0 $. This means that $ R \rightarrow 0 $ pointwise as $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 $. My question is: what is the smallest set of assumptions to ensure that

\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}\xi K(\xi)R\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X-\epsilon\xi\right)d\xi \in \mathrm{o}(1)
\end{align}
as $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 $. It's easy to prove that the other terms will converge when integrated, since $ h\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X\right) $ is periodic and continuous and can be dominated by a constant. Similarly for $ h_2$. This means $ \epsilon\xi K(\xi)R\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(X-\epsilon\xi),X-\epsilon\xi\right) \in L^1 $. Apart from making restrictions on $ K $ or assuming $ R $ takes a certain form, I haven't been able to construct a dominating function. The simplest thing I've been able to deduce is:
let $ P(X-\epsilon\xi) = R\left(\theta,X-\epsilon\xi\right) $, where $ \theta $ maximizes $ R $ for fixed $X,\xi,\epsilon$. If $ \xi K(\xi)P(X-\epsilon\xi) \in L^1 $ and $P(X-\epsilon\xi) $ is increasing for all $|\xi| > a $ for some constant $ a $, then clearly $ P(X-\epsilon\xi)$ is dominated by $P(X-\xi)$ for all $ \epsilon < 1 $ and $ |\xi|> a $. For $ |\xi| < a $, $ P $ is bounded due to its continuity.

I don't have much experience with regard to uniform integrability and sufficient conditions for bringing a limit inside an integral. Any advice would be very welcome.